# Is it correct value of cluster center is refer to a*b (LAB color space) value

Tags: css, matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am working on image processing and I need to segment colour in image into several groups.I am using k-means algorithm to do that.This time, I want to give English name to the colour which already been clustering. this is my coding:

```
   cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
   lab = applycform(a,cform);
   ab = double(lab(:,:,2:3));
   nrows = size(ab,1);
   ncols = size(ab,2);
   ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

   nColors=6;
   [cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', 'Replicates',3);
   pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
   segmented_images = cell(1,3);
   rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
```

as far as I understand, `cluster_center` is refer to `a*b` (lab colour space) value. Is it correct? If so, why I get the value of `cluster_center` more than range value already set (`-128` to `128` for lab color space).

Comment: Why do you think it should be between -128 and 128,  and not 0-255 ?

Comment: @Dan, a is my original image...@Photon, Every time I want to convert using rgb to lab ,(http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab), an error message pop up and its state that value of LAB should be in the range -128 to 128.

Comment: @Photon: The OP is correct. Please read about how the [Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) works.

Comment: It may be defined that way in some or most places, but the real question is how it's implemented in the Matlab code used above.  If the uint8 image is transformed to uint8 Lab and only then converted to double, you would get 0-255